# URL encoding in jsoup not working properly

Tags: jsoup

When trying to fetch a web page using jsoup (org.jsoup 1.15.3) I get MalformedUrlException for URLs that are not encoded.
I can see the code trying to do the encoding (org.jsoup.helper.HttpConnection#encodeUrl(java.net.URL)) but it seems it does not know how to encode all options.

Example failing URL (because of the '[' and ']'):
[https://im-creation-assets.s3-us-west-2.amazonaws.com/CelebrityCars[DE]/20221208JuliaRobertsCarJvo/juliayoung-1___native_1200-627.jpg](https://im-creation-assets.s3-us-west-2.amazonaws.com/CelebrityCars%5BDE%5D/20221208JuliaRobertsCarJvo/juliayoung-1___native_1200-627.jpg)

I can do the encoding myself before calling jsoup, but I still fail if there is a redirect to another URL that needs encoding.
The failure, by the way, is not from encodeUrl (which recovers) - but from org.jsoup.helper.CookieUtil#asUri - which started on this version (I did not have a problem with a former version I was using).

Is it possible to fix the way URLs are encoded?

I am using the following spring code that seems to work well:

```
import org.springframework.web.util.UriComponentsBuilder;
final String encodedUrl = UriComponentsBuilder
  .fromUriString(url)
  .build()
  .encode()
  .toUri()
  .toString();
```

(I am aware I can avoid redirects and do the encoding on each URL myself, but thought it might be a good idea to fix it for everyone...)

Answer (score 0):

This issue is fixed in the (upcoming) release 1.15.4 of jsoup, thanks to your [report](https://github.com/jhy/jsoup/issues/1873).